# How to pass image which is in my local system to form-data and pass that form-data to carry out post request via Axios

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, curl, axios

I am not able to pass form-data in axios correctly,getting error code 422.For reference see the below code. in curl request it is mentioned we have to pass headers and form-data I think I have done everyhing correct not sure about form-data.please look into it.

```
app.post("/images", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var formData = new FormData();

    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "multipart / form-data",
    };

    let resp = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/19/images",
      null, {
        headers: headers,
        params: {
          token: "myToken",
        },
        formData: {
          "image[attachment]": "riceBasm2.jpeg",
          type: "image/jpeg",
        }
      }
    );
    console.log(resp);
    return;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  res.send("Image added succesfully");
});
```

Comment: Include your code from the API endpoint to handle this request. Does it support multipart form upload?

Comment: yes it support .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer as I mentioned the request works with postman,so i searched postman code section and I got the answer.Postman consist code in every language so do check it out if you stuck and when your query works with postman but not when you try it with your own code.

Below code is in Nodejs Axios

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('image[attachment]', fs.createReadStream('/home/kiit/Bharatrath/riceBasm.jpeg'));

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/21/images?token=my_token',
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', 
    'Cookie': 'adonis-session=1b341136aeb0e89d23810f453b28ad40qUCo9HjeNsqhVFl3U0xVd1%2BTlbyFwN7ECZLo7nHYoad4VeEWnEMwXd%2FHT%2BKtXVyYAF6cHway6vNRYZGWIvR5%2BitS%2BuPgL%2FXzS02i77v4BkAvbb23vKqEQ2lb2cukfpfp; adonis-session-values=dbc2abc0c3695f76625c2c1cde19c125E9yRs0sOPTuSSDFpMDgEwAHsXzYJ38p4Y9JReim06COj8QA212fBid4IjEKRTY%2BdlNgA8w5zWpWINrCV50ddONU0IGfUlUBCa9fejdMpdmWmd96N%2FGTbxSih2Fwd1rfSNXg7FsNuGhdcFvyagphawRsUb5xcOjgY2TztZ4CiXsKm2w6Laf8Ye4s4cEM7B2fnngsdD2w3ZczpFco0fpo6yS8JATgW2ze8v%2BVeALFVWhQ%3D', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Code for Curl

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/21/images?token=2aff2732fa39f2064ac21dcfff63139cc20adb2122f8b500' \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Cookie: adonis-session=1b341136aeb0e89d23810f453b28ad40qUCo9HjeNsqhVFl3U0xVd1%2BTlbyFwN7ECZLo7nHYoad4VeEWnEMwXd%2FHT%2BKtXVyYAF6cHway6vNRYZGWIvR5%2BitS%2BuPgL%2FXzS02i77v4BkAvbb23vKqEQ2lb2cukfpfp; adonis-session-values=dbc2abc0c3695f76625c2c1cde19c125E9yRs0sOPTuSSDFpMDgEwAHsXzYJ38p4Y9JReim06COj8QA212fBid4IjEKRTY%2BdlNgA8w5zWpWINrCV50ddONU0IGfUlUBCa9fejdMpdmWmd96N%2FGTbxSih2Fwd1rfSNXg7FsNuGhdcFvyagphawRsUb5xcOjgY2TztZ4CiXsKm2w6Laf8Ye4s4cEM7B2fnngsdD2w3ZczpFco0fpo6yS8JATgW2ze8v%2BVeALFVWhQ%3D' \
--form 'image[attachment]=@/home/kiit/Bharatrath/riceBasm.jpeg'
```